# kernel patch .diff file

Tags: centos, kernel, patch-management

i need to apply patch .diff file to kenerl how to apply it which command should i use after i save the patch on patch.diff file
ps patch is 
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=248716

Comment: What's wrong with just updating the kernel package?

Comment: ive no problem with this i just wanted to learn how to  apply such patch .diff files :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the patch tool. The general syntax is as follows:

```
patch -pnum <patchfile
```

For more info see:

```
man patch
```